# Shiny input text "required argument"

Tags: r, tags, shiny

I'm trying to get this line of code in R shiny :

```
<input id="inputId" type="text" value="value" required/>
```

How to do it with a shiny tag ?

---

I know that

```
tags$input(id="inputId", type="text",  value = "value")
```

produces

```
<input id="inputId" type="text" value="value"/>
```

But I don't know how to add required arg. 
Thanks in advance for you help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 tags$input(id="inputId", type="text",  value = "value", required=NA)
```